How to style and add data-attrs to td-cells via server-side mode in DataTables.js?
Is there a way to pass parameters from ajax which will be converted into class and data- attributes of <td>?
I want to generate in ajax.php something like:
[
    "draw" => 1,
    "recordsTotal" => 1,
    "recordsFiltered" => 1,
    "data" => [
        [
            ["data" => "<span>123</span>", "class" => "col-abc-class", "order" => 123],
            ["data" => "<span>456</span>", "class" => "col-xyz-class", "order" => 456, "param" => "test"]
        ]
    ]
]

and receive in html something like:
<tr>
    <td class="col-abc-class" data-order="123">
        <span>123</span>
    </td>
    <td class="col-xyz-class" data-order="456" data-param="test">
        <span>456</span>
    </td>
</tr>

Is there a universal way to organize it except writing a rule for each column in DataTable initialization?

Use server side processing to accomplish what you asked, but Why would you add html to your ajax response? You can play with your response ajax and add all your html tags using datatables column dict.
Check out data rendring
